# FullCalendar - Unable to make events show using URL of a JSON feed

Tags: json, fullcalendar

I know this question has been asked multiple times on these forums ( I know because I've been roaming these forums the last couple of days in order to find a solution), but I still can't find a proper solution.

I'm using the FullCalendar plug in and trying to get events to show on load via a URL of a JSON feed file. When I insert the object directly in the JS file it works fine:

```
events: [
  {
    "title": "mytitle1",
    "start": "2017-10-12T12:00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-10-12T14:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "mytitle2",
    "start": "2017-10-12T15:00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-10-12T17:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

But when I use a URL the events won't show. This is the JS script. it should have other features such as eventClick, select etc...But I've commented them out as they seem irrelevant to the issue:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header:{
        left: 'prev,next, today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
    buttonIcons:{
        prev: 'left-single-arrow',
        next: 'right-single-arrow'
    },
    editable: true,
    selectable: true,
    allDaySlot: false,
    slotDuration: '00:15:00',
    slotLabelInterval: '01:00:00',

    events: "json.php"
  })
});
```

Eventually I would like to populate the JSON file with input from a database, but for now even creating simple objects in the json.php file, using json_encode and echoing the result doesn't make the events show.

The json.php script:

```
class TestClass{
  var $title;
  var $start;
  var $end;
}

$var1 = new TestClass();
$var1 -> title = "mytitle1";
$var1 -> start = "2017-10-12T12:00:00Z";
$var1 -> end = "2017-10-12T14:00:00Z";

$var2 = new TestClass();
$var2 -> title = "mytitle2";
$var2 -> start = "2017-10-12T15:00:00Z";
$var2 -> end = "2017-10-12T17:00:00Z";

$arr = array($var1, $var2);

$arrjson = json_encode($arr, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT | JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
echo "<pre>" . $arrjson . "</pre>";
```

When running the json.php file, I get a proper JSON string (validated both by jsonlint.com and by inserting directly into the JS file as shown above):

```
[
  {
    "title": "mytitle1",
    "start": "2017-10-12T12:00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-10-12T14:00:00Z"
  },
  {
    "title": "mytitle2",
    "start": "2017-10-12T15:00:00Z",
    "end": "2017-10-12T17:00:00Z"
  }
]
```

But still the events won't show.
I've tried changing the date strings a bit, but this should be the correct ISO8601 format, and again - It does work when inserting directly into the JS file. Also, the json.php file is located in the same directory as the JS file so that should't be a problem.

Iv'e been struggling with this for days. Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION**

What worked for me was to remove the "pre" tags from the json.php file, and add the header:

```
header("Content-type:application/json");
```

Besides that, the json.php file was located in the same folder as the JS file requesting it, but apparently FullCalendar looks for the file in the root directory of the project.

Thanks to ADyson for the help!

Comment: Any errors in your browser console? My first question would be, why are you echoing `"<pre>"` and `"</pre>"` along with the JSON? You're returning JSON, not HTML. Just echo the JSON string on its own. There's a good chance the browser cannot deal with your response because it's not pure JSON. And also set the correct content-type header on the server before you echo, by writing `header("Content-type:application/json");`

Comment: So I made the changes to the JSON file as you described, but still not working.
However, I do get an error in the browser console (Never thought of checking - kind of new to this) which seems relevant:
GET http://localhost / ScheduleManager /json.php?start=2017-10-08&end=2017-10-15&_=1507910799675 404 (Not Found)  : jquery.min.js:4 

Not really familiar with how FullCalander works under the hood sometimes. Why the request for those specific dates?

Comment: 404 Not Found is a general HTTP error which means it simply couldn't find a file at that URL. So check whether the link to your json.php is correct. If what you've printed there is an exact copy of your link, then it looks like you have spaces in the URL which certainly isn't right.

Comment: Aha thank you!! So there were actually two problems, and you stated them both. The first was to add the JSON header to the JSON file and get rid of the <pre> tags. The second was to put the JSON file in the root directory of the project instead of the Javascript folder. Thank you so much!